# c# Left joining 2 DataTable

Tags: c#

I have 2 DataTables with no primary keys on either table. I need all records in DataTable1 to be left joined with DataTable2. I've solved it a couple of ways but are they performant?

Column2 is the soft "key" and I am trying to populate the column 3 field in DataTable1 from DataTable2.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(int));
            dt1.Columns.Add("col2", typeof(string));
            dt1.Columns.Add("col3", typeof(string));
            dt1.Rows.Add(1, "One");
            dt1.Rows.Add(1, "Two");
            dt1.Rows.Add(3, "Two");
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            dt2.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(int));
            dt2.Columns.Add("col2", typeof(string));
            dt2.Columns.Add("col3", typeof(string));
            dt2.Rows.Add(1, "One", "One Description");
            dt2.Rows.Add(2, "Two", "Two Description");

            //Solution 1
            //foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
            //{
            //    row[2] = dt2.Select("col2='" + row[1] + "'")[0]["col3"];
            //}

            foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
            {
                row[2] = dt2.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x["col2"] == row[1]).FirstOrDefault()[2];
            }

            dt1.AsEnumerable().ToList().ForEach(x =>
            Console.WriteLine(
                "col1:{0} col2:{1} col3:{2}"
                , x[0], x[1], x[2])
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**Bonus:** I tried to copy this into .Net Fiddle but it doesn't seem to like the AsEnumerable on the DataTable.  [Go .Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9B1bzc)

Comment: Where do you get data for datatables from?

Comment: One comes from an API and the other from a stored procedure

Comment: First of all I would operate with data, not with datatables. Then if your second data set has unique keys (such as 'One', 'Two') I would make a dictionary from it to make search more faster. Iterate first data set and find description value in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LINQ GroupJoin` for that:

```
var result = dt1.Select()
    .GroupJoin(dt2.Select(), t1 => t1[1], t2 => t2[1], (t1, t2) => { t1[2] = t2.FirstOrDefault()?[2]; return t1; })
    .ToList();
```